# Use of 'such as for instance'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Is it correct to use `such as for instance` ? or it should be `such as` instead ?

Example:

> Other techniques can be considered, such as for instance techniques B and C.

Also, in the above sentence we shoul use `and` or `or` ?

Comment: Access  your dictionary, please, and learn the meaning of the adjective _redundant._ "Such as for instance" is an examplar of _redundancy._ Either _such as_ **or** _for instance_ would suffice. When used together, they indicate that the speaker or writer is only marginally literate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use 'for instance' or 'for example" after the phrase 'such as' as these  phrases are synonyms of such as.

You use and, not or, before the last example when you present two or more examples.